# gif spinner doesn't appear when submitting form using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to add a loading gif to my form when the user clicks the submit button using ajax and I want to also disable the submit button. I have tried it this way but it doesn't work. My button does have an ID of 'submit'

```
 <script type="text/javascript">                                 
// we will add our javascript code here
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() {
        var str = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contactfinal.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(response) {
 $('submit').html('<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; sending...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#error').html(response);

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you want to disable your button outside just before your ajax call. Right now it will disable the button (assuming code is correct) after the server call responded. The user can do infinite number of posts in this time.

If the id is submit, use $('#submit') to find that element with jquery.

Not sure why you change it's html and try to disable something as well, seems you need to chose either one of those options.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "contactfinal.php",
  data: str,
  success: function(response) {
    // $('#error').html(response);
  }
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('submit').html('<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; sending...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  },
  complete: function() {
    $('submit').html('').attr('disabled', '');
  },
});
```

`beforeSend` method will take action while ajax is waiting for the server response, and `complete` will also take the action, after the ajax determined the browser completely receive the server response.

Hope you'll get the idea.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work but maybe I just didn't incorporate it into the rest of the script properly? I don't know how to paste code into my response. I tried but it says it's too long.

Comment: You can try jsfiddle to present what you did, and paste here again the link.

Comment: Okay, I haven't done this before so hopefully this is correct. https://jsfiddle.net/9x8rh9w8/#&togetherjs=PKGwrGgF9P

Comment: I tried something else which seems to work. I just want to know if the code is acceptable. https://jsfiddle.net/9x8rh9w8/3/#&togetherjs=PKGwrGgF9P

Comment: Yes, As long as it works, then that's it, there no wrong with your code

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() {

        var str = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contactfinal.php",
            data: str,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#submit").hide();
                 $("#loading").show();
                  },
            success: function(response) {
               $('#error').html(response);
                $("#submit").show();
                $("#loading").hide();

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```